Printing Color using Ruby
Using Replit as my IDE, I'm trying to create a program that outputs color palettes (either in the console, or textfile, or something). How can I output something that shows the color of a specific rgb (or other) value?
I believe the gem Colorize and Rainbow don't allow you to customize the colors of the text.
I've tried some game creation gems, like Ruby2D or Gosu, but because they are dependent on SDL2, I faced issues because of Replit and my linux platform.
Please help, I'm getting a little desperate here because this is for a school project. Thanks guys

Most terminals have some color capabilities, but not for the whole RGB space. You'll have to write a graphical app, or generate an HTML file and view it in a browser


I'm trying to create a program that outputs color palettes (either in the console, or textfile, or something)

Color palettes are usually stored in specific file formats, see https://www.selapa.net/swatches/colors/fileformats.php for a detailed technical rundown.
You can generate such files yourself following the file format descriptions or by using a library, e.g. ASEPalette.
Note that this won't output any colors. You have to open the color palette in a graphics program like GIMP or Photoshop.


How can I output something that shows the color of a specific rgb (or other) value?

That's a different task. Ruby script don't have a GUI and can't output color directly. They can output text or generate an image file.
Text-wise, you can output ANSI escape sequences. These codes are interpreted by many terminals – including Replit – and will result in colored text.
To get (24-bit) RGB colors, there is:
ESC[38;2;⟨r⟩;⟨g⟩;⟨b⟩ m Select RGB foreground color
ESC[48;2;⟨r⟩;⟨g⟩;⟨b⟩ m Select RGB background color

In Ruby: (\e is the escape character, \e[0m resets the colors)
puts "\e[38;2;244;128;36mOrange foreground\e[0m"
puts "\e[48;2;244;128;36mOrange background\e[0m"

Which will print as: (in Replit)


Image-wise, you could use ChunkyPNG, an old but working PNG library with no external dependecies.
In Replit, create a "Ruby" project, and add the gem to your Gemfile:
gem "chunky_png"

Then change main.rb to:
require "chunky_png"

color = ChunkyPNG::Color.rgb(244, 128, 36) # Stack Overflow orange
image = ChunkyPNG::Image.new(100, 100, color)
image.save("color.png")

and run the project.
This should install the gem and generate a new file color.png in your project's root:

You can open the PNG inside Replit or download it.
